# livepatch is on but software and updates app says otherwise, and when you switch the toggle on it says "Could not enable Livepatch. Please try again."

Tags: canonical-livepatch

[image: livepatch icon and software and updates app]

its basically just the title

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
64-bit
42.9
Wayland

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Have you tried messing around with the [Ubuntu Pro commands to enable live patch](https://ubuntu.com/security/livepatch/docs/livepatch/how-to/enable)? `sudo pro enable livepatch` should enable livepatch. If not, then please post the errors. Also, you may need to attach your token to verify your account using the following command: `sudo pro attach [TOKEN]` where `[TOKEN]` is your actual token (replace `[TOKEN]` with your token). And then run `sudo pro enable livepatch`

Comment: What is the output of `uname -r`?  It appears that the `canonical-livepatch` does not support the `6.5.0-14-generic` Kernel.

Comment: oh no......

sudo pro enable livepatch
[sudo] password for ad1340: 
One moment, checking your subscription first
Livepatch is already enabled.
See: sudo pro status

Comment: uname -r
6.5.0-14-generic

Comment: Yep, Kernel 6.5.0-14-generic does not work with canonical-livepatch.  You get these two lines when you check the status on it:  `kernel state: ✗ kernel is not covered by Livepatch` and `patch state: ✓ no livepatches available for kernel 6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1-generic`

Comment: nooo but now what do I do because I installed ubuntu on here before and livepatch worked fineee

Comment: @AD1340Official Last time this happened basically you just had to wait for the update to `canonical-livepatch` to support the kernel version or the next LTS release.  It is a snap app so any updates for it should download and install automatically.  You are also more than welcome to file a bug against `canonical-livepatch` about it not supporting Kernel `6.5.0-14-generic`.  You would just email them at `snaps@canonical.com`